# Any Robocopy GUI that can run from CMD in WinRE?

Tags: robocopy

Please correct me if I'm wrong, I wish I were:
I'd like to use Robocopy from Command Prompt in the Windows 10 Recovery Environment (by booting to the WinRE and opening Command Prompt).
I learnt there're some nice Robocopy GUIs such as RoboMirror and others that make it easier to use  Robocopy.

I guess these wouldn't work from the Command Prompt in the Windows 10 RE, right? I mean, if I navigated to the .exe for any of these GUI it wouldn't work I guess.

I'd welcome any clarification :-)

Comment: No, GUIs don't "work" from a command prompt (CLI - command line interface) in general. Not sure if you could add a GUI version of Robocopy to the RE directly though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It seems only some native Windows apps would run from the CLI, such as regedit.exe

Comment: I use robocopy as a CLI command all the time (try to run `robocpy.exe`), not sure I understand your comment?!